# phoneNumberMnemonics. NoneType object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
def phoneNumberMnemonics(phoneNumber):
    result = []
    return helper(phoneNumber, result)


def helper(phoneNumber, result):
    if len(phoneNumber) == 0:
        result.append("")
        return result

    new_number = phoneNumber[0]
    print(new_number)
    last_iteration = helper(phoneNumber[1:],result)
    new_number_letter = numberToLetter(new_number)

    for item in last_iteration:
            for letter in new_number_letter:
                result.append(letter + item)

    return result

def numberToLetter(input):
    map = {1: ["1"], 2: ["a","b","c"], 3: ["d", "e", "f"], 4: ["g", "h", "i"], 5: ["j", "k", "l"], 6: ["m", "n", "o"], 7: ["p", "q", "r", "s"], 8: ["t", "u", "v"], 9: ["w", "x", "y", "z"], 0: ["0"]}
    return map.get(input)

# print(numberToLetter(5))

print(phoneNumberMnemonics("890"))
```

I am not sure why this program always gives me

```
File "/Users/pythonProject/main.py", line 18, in helper
    for letter in new_number_letter:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Not sure why new_number_letter is not iterable with my test case "890"

Comment: `"1"` is not `1`. See what `map.get(input)` returns.

Comment: are you expecting this output : `['t8', 'u8', 'v8', 't9', 'u9', 'v9', 't0', 'u0', 'v0', 'w8', 'x8', 'y8', 'z8', 'w9', 'x9', 'y9', 'z9', 'w0', 'x0', 'y0', 'z0', '08', '09', '00']`